# Why doesn't my python script send COOKIES together?

Tags: python, urllib

After a long time writing this small script, it finally worked; or better to say, it's almost done. I am having just a small problem. I am not able to send COOKIES as add.headers in the `urllib.request`. What am I doing wrong? I need to send a given COOKIE or the website will not allow me to download the .pdf file, but I believe I'm doing this the wrong way.

Here is my code; please let me know what is wrong:

```
import os
import threading
import urllib.request

from queue import Queue

class Downloader(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded File Downloader"""

    def __init__(self, queue):
        """Initialize the thread"""
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """Run the thread"""
        while True:
            # gets the url from the queue
            url = self.queue.get()

            # download the file
            self.download_file(url)

            # send a signal to the queue that the job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

    def download_file(self, url):
        """Download the file"""
        handle = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        faturanum = 20184009433300
        fatura = str(faturanum)
        fname = fatura + ".pdf"
        handle.addheaders = [('Cookie', 'ASP.NET_SessionId=zstuzktl0x1laoqhxgkm4ign')]
        with open(fname, "wb") as f:
            while True:
                chunk = handle.read(1024)
                if not chunk: break
                f.write(chunk)

def main(urls):
    """
    Run the program
    """
    queue = Queue()

    # create a thread pool and give them a queue
    for i in range(5):
        t = Downloader(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    # give the queue some data
    for url in urls:
        queue.put(url)

    # wait for the queue to finish
    queue.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ["https://pagamentodigitaltsting.com/Fatura/Pdf?nrFatura=20193981821"]
    main(urls)
```

What is wrong that I can not send cookies with the request? As you can see, the website is being served through https. Once the page loads, it renders a pdf file.

Comment: Maybe the SessionId is old?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is, but have you tried using the requests library? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ I've had good luck with it

Comment: no, the sessioid is fresh .. i gotit right now. As for the requests library, What is your suggestion ?? can you show me the code difference here in my code ?

Comment: I need to open the url before it download the content (pdf). what is wrong in the code ??? I am not being able to find... cookie is not being sent... or I am doing something wrong...

Comment: someone please help me to attach corretly cookie in my code!